# Sharepoint 2010 - Error while deploying visual studio workflow on production

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am updating an already build workflow. Before it was working fine on both Development and Production servers. After making changes when I am deploying it on Development server, it is working fine. But when I deploy it on Production server, it shows error, "Error Occurred".

To know the origin of the error, I re-build the project with logging on a list. (I am adding items on list from workflow code). Now again, its working fine on Development server. But on Production it says, "Failed on Start (retrying)".

The Solution is on farm level and its features is on site level.

PS. This workflow is created on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into ULS Logs to find out what really happened inside SP.
U can find them at 
Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS